# AWS Appsync resolvers for updated related tables

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-appsync

I am trying to write a resolver for related entities.

Here is how my schema looks.

```
type User{
id:ID!
name: String!
posts:[Post] #Resolver 1
}

type Post{
id:ID!,
title: String!
body: String!
}

type CreatePostInput{
id:ID!,
title: String!
body: String!
}
type mutation{
addUserPost(userid:ID!, input:CreatePostInput!): Post
}
```

Now I added a resolver for posts (see #resolver 1) as

```
{
"version" : "2017-02-28",
"operation" : "Scan",
 "key": {
    "userid" : { "S" : "${context.source.id}" }
},
}
```

Now I added a resolver for the mutation addUserPost as

```
{
  "version" : "2017-02-28",
  "operation" : "PutItem",
   "key": {
      "userid" : { "S" : "${context.arguments.userid}" },
     "input" : $util.dynamodb.toDynamoDBJson(${context.arguments.input})     
     }    
}
```

Now when i run the query

```
mutation addnewposttest{
  addChapterToCourse(addUserPost:"c85a0508-ee0e-4ad8-8629-34880e1c6d74",
    input:{
      title:"Demo",
      body:"Test Body",
      id: "c85a0508-c85a0-508c-85a-0508"
    }){
      id
    }
}
```

I get DynamoDB:AmazonDynamoDBException as One or more parameter values were invalid: Missing the key id in the item (Service: AmazonDynamoDBv2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ValidationException; Request ID: XXXXXXXXXXXX

I tried changing the data source for the second resolver, but with no luck. I did not find any good documentation form AWS except for [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/configuring-resolvers.html#aws-appsync-configuring-resolvers) , but this talks about simple string data type, not for object type collection.

Can someone help me understand, how to deal with relationships in resolvers? Thanks

Comment: You have `courseid` in the resolver for addUserPost. Should it be `userid`?

Comment: Thanks @LisaMShon for pointing it out, that was some copy paste error while posting here.

Comment: I think you also have the wrong template for #resolver1. `Scan` operation doesn't support the `key` element

Answer (score 1):

I was referring to two separate data tables and to store the data in two tables I need to use BatchUpdate item and specify the table names. However, I could not do it as in my usecase, i had to insert in one table and update in another table.

Finally, I ended up copying the Id in another collection and building an index on it.

This is how my final schema looked

```
type User{
id:ID!
name: String!
posts:[Post] #Resolver 1 -
}

type Post{
id:ID!,
userId:ID!# I will look for source.id on this field
title: String!
body: String!
}
```

Thanks everyone for pitching in!

Answer (score 0):

As I commented, you have some update to make.

But the main problem is that your resolver template for addUserPost contains `userid` but it looks like you need to change it to `id`. It looks like your User type or the Post type don't have a field named `userid`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. See this article, https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/configuring-resolvers.html, I just followed this. userid corresponds to the parameters(keys) for the mutation. Now I learned hard way that this works only in case of both of these entities live in the same table and has same data source.